# Django getting an objects foreignkey

Tags: django

I have an object called userprofile, which has a city ('ciudad') field. I'm trying to get it with current_user.ciudad but I get an error message "Ciudad matching query does not exist". Traceback: http://dpaste.com/2BMH8EG

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    current_user = self.request.user.userprofile
    print(current_user.ciudad)
    return context
```

My models look like this

```
class Ciudad(models.Model):
    ciudad = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ciudad

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=".")
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=".")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="error")
    telefono = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ciudad = models.ForeignKey(Ciudad, default=0, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    is_productor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_nodo = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Answer (score 3):

Error Traceback

> Ciudad matching query does not exist.
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Gonzalo\Desktop\webdevtests\django4\biodem_dj\firstpage\views.py"
>   in get_context_data
>     69.         print(**current_user.ciudad**)

The error message is self-explanatory.  Current user is `self.request.user.userprofile` and it does not have any corresponding Ciudad.
This error occurred because you deleted Ciudad object which is referenced by some UserProfile objects. Since you have `ciudad = models.ForeignKey(Ciudad, default=0, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)` in `UserProfile Model`. So, now all the UserProfile objects which are referencing to the Ciudad object which you deleted will now point to Ciudad object with id 0 and you don't have any Ciudad object with id = 0 in your database.

Comment: imho, if a user without `ciudad` is not sensible in your use case, you might want to change the field to `ForeignKey(Ciudad, on_delete=PROTECT)`, and allow in the UI that `ciudad` objects can be created if necessary. It will require a migration with a default value, however, which is non-trivial. If `ciudad` is not really required then change it to `ForeignKey(Ciudad, on_delete=PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(current_user.ciudad_id)
```

check if above code print 0(default value), maybe you didnot set the ciudad for current user